# Can you search by the parcel number shown in the "What's Here" pop-up on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, parcel

When you right click on a location in Google Maps and select "What's Here", it usually provides an address and the coordinates.  However when I click inside a lot (e.g. on a farm) I often get a parcel number and no address (see screen shot below).  If you type those numbers back into Google Maps search bar, it doesn't find it.  Is there a way to input the parcel number into Google Maps so that it can find the location?

[image: Google Maps Screenshot]

Comment: do you have a link to the location that shows this 11 digit number?

Comment: They are parcel numbers, example Parcel Number: R0137617. https://www.google.com/maps/place/R0137617,+CO+80102,+USA/@39.8648828,-104.4759906,954m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x876c5a9f8ad5b683:0xd427d2a483be53e6!8m2!3d39.8647651!4d-104.4734219

Comment: Yes I've heard someone else say they are parcel numbers.  And, checking a parcel search service I see it matches.  So, is there a way to search in Google Maps using the parcel number?

Comment: New questions should be posted separately. See this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/k3szta49co0/76lCOZVECgAJ @Mapperz Please post as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Jon thank you for the link.  I updated the question to be more specific, since I technically asked two questions in the original.  Though, I guess the answer is "no".